# How can you make Svelte variables that are dependent on params reactive?

Tags: routes, svelte

I'm trying to figure out routing and responsiveness in Svelte.
I have a very simple REPL set up: https://svelte.dev/repl/e366816d12d04fb4ac982b7c37058655?version=3.47.0

my App file specifies my routes. I just want to pass the name of a state into the path each time. That works fine.

```
        <script>
            import Router from 'svelte-spa-router';
            import State from './State.svelte'
            
            const routes = {
              "/state/:stateName": State,
            }
        </script>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="/#/state/California">California</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#/state/Idaho">Idaho</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#/state/Montana">Montana</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#/state/Oregon">Oregon</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#/state/Washington">Washington</a></li>
        </ul>

        <Router {routes}/>
```

In State.svelte, I export params so that I can print the state name that I passed in. However, I also want to show some other data.

The way I have it set up now, currentPop shows up correctly when I click on the first state, but then as I click through the other states, that population number remains the same. How can I update my code so that the population is responsive?
Thanks!

```
            <script>
                export let params;
                import * as d3 from "d3";

                let states = [{"ID State":"04000US06","State":"California","ID Year":2019,"Year":"2019","Population":39512223,"Slug State":"california"},{"ID State":"04000US16","State":"Idaho","ID Year":2019,"Year":"2019","Population":1787065,"Slug State":"idaho"},{"ID State":"04000US30","State":"Montana","ID Year":2019,"Year":"2019","Population":1068778,"Slug State":"montana"},{"ID State":"04000US41","State":"Oregon","ID Year":2019,"Year":"2019","Population":4217737,"Slug State":"oregon"},{"ID State":"04000US53","State":"Washington","ID Year":2019,"Year":"2019","Population":7614893,"Slug State":"washington"}]

                let currentState, currentPop;

                for(i=0;i<states.length;i++){
                    currentState = states.filter((d) => d.State == params.stateName);
                        currentPop = currentState[0].Population;
                }
                
            </script>
            <p>
                the great state of {params.stateName}
            </p>

            2019 population: {currentPop}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the update part [responsive using `$`](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive):

```js
$: for(i=0;i<states.length;i++) { //...
```

Svelte will track the dependencies of the statement/block and execute it again if any of the dependencies change.

---

The code can be [simplified to this](https://svelte.dev/repl/910877e77be44141b50b957adc78efed?version=3.47.0), by the way:

```js
$: currentState = states.find((d) => d.State == params.stateName);
$: currentPop = currentState.Population;
```